# upgrading turbolinks leads the css to stop loading

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, turbolinks

My rails application stops to load css files and returns errors like below:

```
".add_icon" failed to @extend ".fa-plus-circle".
The selector ".fa-plus-circle" was not found.
Use "@extend .fa-plus-circle !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
```

My js and css were not loading properly and as per suggestions I am just trying to upgrade turbo links using `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'`

If I comment out the gem and gem files from js the application starts to work but does not load my resources without page refresh.

I am forced to reload my page again.

My js looks like:

```
//= require jquery.min
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require common
//= require owl.carousel.min.js
//= require modernizr
//= require parallax
//= require toggle
//= require modernizr
// require_tree .
```

My css file:

```
* require_tree .
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require style
 *= require owl.carousel
 *= require owl.theme
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require refinery/formatting
 *= require refinery/theme
 *= require_self
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I struggled with turbolinks. I'm using Rails 5. I found solution by putting this code below to my xxx.coffee file:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', -> 
 # Your code goes here
```

If you are using pure js instead of coffee try this:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  # Your code goes here
})
```

Again, it depends on Rails version you are using. In Rails 5 turbolinks has been re-written, and doesn't use the same event names as in previous versions.

Sorry, I couldn't comment on your question as I don't have enough points so I posted here as answer. Can you provide more info? Which Rails version are you using? Can you send Gemfile? Have you done bundle update?

I hope it helps